# Commerce Search API with Custom field search

Tags: commerce, search

I have a Custom search form with multiple fields on my front page. After clicking on submit button, user would be routed to search result page. (Ideally, a Commerce search view). On search result page, all facets blocks are enabled.

Products are mapped with Commerce Stores (cmp_store). I have used field collection for Store so Seller can add multiple stores. Each store has Zip code associated with it.

I am getting zip code in my search facets.
But if User has not entered zip code then I want search result based on User's current location + 25 kms radius. Sorting should be location based.

I guess I have to alter the search query. Not sure how to alter query.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have added related fields to the index configuration page under the "fields" tab. First have added the store then the zip code.